# C# use GroupBy within OrderBy

Tags: c#, sorting

I have such a collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Playlist> AllArtists;
```

And `Playlist` has a field `ObservableCollection<Music> Songs` and `Music` has a `string` property called `Album`.

I want to sort the `AllArtists` in a descending order by the number of distinct albums.

How should I do that?

This is my failed attempt:

```
AllArtists.OrderByDescending(playlist => playlist.Songs.GroupBy(music => music.Album).Count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can solve your problem:

```
IEnumerable<Playlist> playlistsOrderedByAlbumCount =
    AllArtists
        .Select(p =>
            new
            {
                playlist = p,
                // Here we count number of unique albums in the current playlist.
                count = p.Songs.Select(s => s.Album).Distinct().Count()
            })
        // And then order playlists in descending order by number of unique albums.
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.count)
        .Select(p => p.playlist);

AllArtists = new ObservableCollection<Playlist>(playlistsOrderedByAlbumCount);
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z2wDsE) that demonstrates this solution.